# .Net Web Service Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: c#, java, .net

I am encountering a **Connection reset by peer: socket write error** while trying to invoke a .Net web service.

**Scenario:**
I have a web service client (created from Java using Eclipse) that consumes a .Net web service (created from C#) and is deployed on a IIS web server.  What the client does is it reads the content of a file as binary and turn it into a String input (let's call it binaryContentInput).  Now, this binaryContentInput will be used as an input when invoking the .Net web service.

**Findings:**
When the file is 3 Mb and below, my code is working fine.  But when the file is 4Mb and above, my code is encountering the socket write error.

**Output from Eclipse when encountered the error**: http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=50e68c5986083

**Encoding/Decoding code found on the internet:** http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=50e68ce6c31b3

**General Objective:** To transfer a file from one server to another (they are both inside the same firewall)

I've tried googling around based on the error but I haven't found any working solution yet.  Can somebody lend a hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Look on exceptions on .Net side - most likly some configuration setting limits request size to 5Mb (which is likly value for base64 encoded 3MB file).

Comment: Hi Alexei, Thanks for the help!  I've tried adding **<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151" />** on my web.config of Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition and I can now transfer files higher than 5mb.  But when I deployed it on my IIS Web server and updated it's web.config, the socket write error appeared again.  What did I missed?